# What type of trees can Ueki make?

Tags: the-law-of-ueki

In the anime **Law of Ueki**, Ueki has the power to "turn trash into trees".

[image: Ueki's Tree-making skill]

What kind of tree(s) does he turn trash into? Can he control what tree he creates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [wiki](http://lou.wikia.com/wiki/K%C5%8Dsuke_Ueki)

> Although the power to turn trash into trees may seem weak, Ueki can be
>   creative with it, making wood darts, wood clubs and wood vines. He is
>   able to win most battle which may seem impossible, beating someone
>   with 299 talents when he only had 11. He can even make trees strong
>   enough to travel directly through cars.
>
> **Its seen that he can make any tree he wants**, making a chestnut tree to
>   counter Taira's fire attacks with the chestnuts flying out of the tree
>   and shooting at the opponent(but really wanted to make them hot enough
>   to eat).